# maintaining state in wordpress using php classes - object lifespan

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I have created an html form from scratch and included it by using the Wordpress Shortcode API. The form is a table based on a collection of user data. The collection is a php class. In the constructor of the collection I attempt to register the form 'post' action with

```
add_action( 'admin_post_my_form_action' function() {
    handle_post_data();
}
```

the form is declared like this:

```
<form action="' . esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ) . '" method="post">
```

and has a hidden 'input' field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_form_action">
```

all should be well...

BUT, the form handler never gets called.

by adding debugging into the __construct() and __destruct() methods i see that the Collection object has a very short lifespan. The collection object is being destroyed before the callback can be called. (this is surprising as presumably wordpress core has a callback handle to it)

I have tried to keep the Collection object alive by declaring it in global scope and by using a singleton pattern with a static instance attribute. Neither approach works.

Is there a nice wordpressy way of keeping state over time?

thanks in anticipation

addendum: When I put the add_action hook outside a function or class, the callback works. This, however, doesn't solve my problem.. I need the Collection object to persist long enough that I can use it in the callback. -J

Answer (score 0):

add_action needs to be outside of function or class as this code needs to be called before WordPress starts processing data. If you put this into a class you would need to instantiate this class and call function containing this code to register hook.

I'm not sure what do you mean by Collection. All data from the form is available through the $_POST variable. Try just print all request data using var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) and see what you'll get from this.

Comment: collection=data arrays encapsulated in a class.

Comment: sequence of events is: add_shortcode() .. when the page is to be shown the shortcode callback instantiates the Collection class, the constructor of which then adds an action hook to handle the form POST action... All the form data is in the _POST array as expected but I want to use that data to update the Collection object.